# How do you generate a Code Map diagram of your project in Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, class-diagram, code-map

Microsoft's documentation is incredibly confusing or lacking in showing us how to generate a code structure / Code Map.

On [visualstudio.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F), in the "Compare Visual Studio 2015 Offerings" table, under Architecture and Modeling, it is shown that "Visualize solutions with Dependency Graphs and **Code Maps**" is supported in Visual Studio Community.

Old examples show that Code Maps are under the Architecture Explorer tab, but I don't have that tab in my VS. I also tried searching for Code Maps in Quick Launch, and got nothing.

The only thing I can do is go to File > New > File and make a new Directed Graph Document (.dgml). I can drag in classes to it, but that's not a generated diagram, it's a new blank one.

PS: The same happens for Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, not just Community 2015.

[EDIT] Apparently there IS an Architecture tab in VS Enterprise 2015. I was trying something called "**Blend** for Visual Studio Enterprise 2015" which seems to just be Visual Studio Community 2015... Great stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't create Code Maps with VS 2015 Community or Professional. You need Enterprise to create them. They can be *viewed* in the Community or Professional Edition, after they have been created with VS 2015 Enterprise.

This is documented in [Compare Visual Studio 2015 Offerings page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs). If you look at the "Architecture and Modeling" section you will see that in the Community and Professional columns Code Map has footnote no. 3. It says: "Read-Only diagrams".

Comment: Thanks! I had read that "3" footnote, but didn't take "Read-Only diagrams" to mean "Only read diagrams". "Read-Only" (at least to me) implies you can autogenerate and view them but not edit them.